# Prove $\sum \limits_{k=0}^{n} (k+1){n \choose k} = 2^{n-1} (n+2)$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, induction

How can I prove this statement using induction? Im stuck at getting the Induction step simplified:

$\sum \limits_{k=0}^{n+1} (k+1){n+1 \choose k} = 2^{n+1-1}  (n+1+2)$

Comment: are you required to use induction, or can you use another approach?

Comment: im required to use induction, sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the assumption that
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(k+1)=2^{n-1}(n+2)$$
we need to complete the inductive step by showing that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}(k+1)=2^{n}(n+3).$$
The main annoying issue here that we must find a way to get around is the binomial coefficient $\binom{n+1}{k}$. We have to eventually use the inductive hypothesis with the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$, but we can't do so directly when the left hand side of what we want to prove has $\binom{n+1}{k}$---so what we need to do now is to simplify $\binom{n+1}{k}$ into something in terms of $\binom{n}{k}$ to apply the inductive hypothesis.

The way to do so is by the following identity:

> $$\binom{n+1}{k}=\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k-1}$$ for all positve integers $n,k$ with $k\leq n$.

There are many ways to prove this equality, for example by just invoking the explicit formula for the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$. Now we are already almost done. We simplify:
$$\begin{split}\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}(k+1)&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n}{k}(k+1)+\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n}{k-1}(k+1)\\
&=2^{n-1}(n+2)+\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(k+2)\\&=2^{n-1}(n+2)+\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(k+1)+\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\\&=2\times 2^{n-1}(n+2)+2^n = 2^n(n+3),\end{split}$$
as desired. Make sure you think through what I did above to see the two places where I invoked the inductive hypothesis, and why that was made possible by the manipulation to split up $\binom{n+1}{k}$ into something that looks like $\binom{n}{k}$. Also note the places where the indexing variables don't seem to match up with what's in the inductive hypothesis, and convince yourself that what I did was indeed valid by e.g. writing out small cases. Once you've done so, the inductive proof should become more transparent.

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: @AnotherNoone No problem. Make sure you really understand what I did---passively reading a proof someone else wrote will not allow you to completely get it. Cheers!

Comment: Im redoing the steps as you did, to fully understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : Have you tried using [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) for the induction step

In summary. 
Suppose that this is a true for $n$:
$$ I.H. \ : \sum_{k=0}^n (k+1)\binom{n}{k} = 2^{n-1}(n+2)$$

And you want to value
$$ S = \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} (k+1)\binom{n+1}{k} $$

If it's easier for you, you can start removing the case $k=0$ and $k=n+1$,
$$ S = 1 + (n+2) + \sum_{k=1}^{n} (k+1)\binom{n+1}{k}$$

and then using Pascal's triangle
$$ S = 1 + (n+2) + \sum_{k=1}^{n} (k+1)\left[\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k-1}\right]$$

Can you finish using the induction hypothesis? Try to transform this last sum in order to use the induction hypothesis.

> Start by splitting the sum is two, the first one is almost the induction hypothesis, lacking the initial term $k=0$.

**Edit** you will also need the fact that
$$ \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} = 2^n$$

Comment: I have no idea on how to proceed further.. (i mean, this makes sense to me and I kind of understand what youre doing, but i dont know what would be the next step to do)

Comment: What have you tried? Have you split the sum, one sum for each binomial coefficient? Does the first term looks familiar? The second one, try to change the index from $k=1\ldots n$ to $k=0\ldots n-1$

Comment: Can you edit your question in order to show the advance? I don't understand how you "substitute the first sum for $k2^n$". $k$ is only define inside the sum, you can get $k$ out of the sum.

Comment: ( i made a mistake when i substituted there )